# How can I block calls from unknown domains/IP to my REST API?

Tags: django, rest, security, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I want to block calls to my Django REST API (www.backend_django.com) from unknown origins, for example, I have a website under the domain "www.example.com" I want to allow only to this site to be able to do request to my API.

In order to do this, I have configured Django-Cors-Headers in the following way:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["www.backend_django.com", "backend_django.com"]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False 
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://backend_django.com',
    'https://www.backend_django.com',
    'https://example.com',
    'https://www.example.com', )

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'backend_django.com',
    'example.com']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

In order to test it, I have done a call from Postman using my computer and have successfully done a request still to the API.

Did I set up something bad in the settings? How can I archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS restrictions won't prevent other hosts from making direct requests to your API.

If you need granular restrictions then you could use something like django-iprestrict.

If you need to restrict the whole backend app it's easier via web server settings .htaccess or similar.