# Easiest/Best way to restrict people/unknown from accessing Django API?

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I've written a Django API and it works well however I want to restrict people/unknown hosts from writing requests to the API. This is because I have a React Frontend deployed at `example.com` and I want to make sure that only `example.com` can send requests to the API.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this.
I was trying to do research into cors however from looking at this thread [How can I block calls from unknown domains/IP to my REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349078/how-can-i-block-calls-from-unknown-domains-ip-to-my-rest-api), it seems like cors can't prevent other hosts/unknown from making requests? I want to secure my API such that only my Frontend host at `example.com` can make requests to the API and other hosts can't (including stuff like Postman and curl shouldn't be able to make requests).

How do I go about doing this? Any help in the right direction is very much appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Comment: check this video, he also provides the source code, maybe it will provide some insight. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjMP0hspNLE&t=2994s

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions you should consider:

- [Django user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/)
- IP restrictions

  - see [Authenticate by IP address in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383540/authenticate-by-ip-address-in-django)
  - this can also be handled from services like AWS CloudFront & WAF